# Print XML node using XPath in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to print complex XML's node values using XPath, I have attached an image for helping to see the path which I need to reach (red underline).
[image: XML image]
Original XML file can be found [here](http://mobitech.us.lt/document.xml)

I was trying something like that:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('document.xml');

    echo "<strong>Using direct method...</strong><br />";
    $names = $xml->xpath('/w:document/w:body/w:tbl[0]/w:tr[1]/w:tc[0]/w:p/w:r/w:t');
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo "Found $name<br />";
    }

?>
```

This method I am using to replace this node:

```
 $file = "document.xml";                                        
    $fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("error");
    $str = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $xml = new DOMDocument();                                
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->loadXML($str) or die("Error");

    $root   = $xml->documentElement;
    $fnode  = $root->childNodes->item(0);

    $ori    = $fnode->childNodes->item(1);                      
    $ori1    = $ori->childNodes->item(3);
    $ori2   = $ori1->childNodes->item(1);
    $ori3   = $ori2->childNodes->item(1);
    $ori4   = $ori3->childNodes->item(1);
    $ori5   = $ori4->childNodes->item(1);
        $wt     = $xml->createElement("w:t");
    $wtText = $xml->createTextNode("".$name." ".$item."");
    $wt->appendChild($wtText);
        $ori4->replaceChild($wt,$ori5);
        $xml->save("document.xml");
```

Comment: edited my post, I can reach that node using PHPDOM and replace that node, but I dont know how to read only this one xml node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// Load XML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("document.xml");

// Use xpath to grab the node in question. I copied your xpath
// query as-is, assuming it was capable of targetting exactly
// the node you are trying to replace. If it returns more than
// one node, then only the first will be replaced.
// If this isn't what you want, I suggest modifying your xpath
// query to match exactly the single node you want to replace.
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$oldElement = $xpath->query("/w:document/w:body/w:tbl[0]/w:tr[1]/w:tc[0]/w:p/w:r/w:t")->item(0);
$newElement = $doc->createElementNS("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "w:t", $name . " " . $item);

// Replace old element with new element
$oldElement->parentNode->replaceChild($newElement, $oldElement);

?>
```